# If eigenspaces $V_{\lambda} (\phi )= V_{\lambda} (\phi ‘)$ then $ \phi = \phi ‘$

Tags: linear-algebra, diagonalization

Let $\phi, \phi ‘$ be diagonalisable elements of $\text{End}_K(V)$ where $V$ is finite dimensional over $K$.

Setting $V_\lambda (\phi )=\ker (\phi - \lambda \text{Id}_V )$ if we have $V_\lambda (\phi )= V_\lambda (\phi ‘ ) $ for all $\lambda \in \mathbb{C}$ then how can we show that $\phi = \phi ‘ $?

Comment: How do $K$ and $\mathbb{C}$ relate?

Comment: Sorry. $K= \mathbb{C}$

Comment: Then can you show this? $$V = \sum_{\lambda \in \mathbb{C}} V_\lambda(\phi)$$

Comment: Yes I know that this is true

Answer (score 1):

In the comments, you have stated that you *know* $$V = \sum_{\lambda\in\mathbb{C}} V_\lambda(\phi),$$
so I'm going to assume that below.

---

For $x \in V$, this tells you that there is some finite set $F \subset \mathbb{C}$ and some $x_\lambda \in V_\lambda(\phi)=V_\lambda(\phi')$ for each $\lambda \in F$ such that $$x = \sum_{\lambda\in F} x_\lambda.$$

Applying $\phi$ and $\phi'$ shows
$$\phi(x) = \sum_{\lambda\in F} \phi(x_\lambda) = \sum_{\lambda\in F} \lambda x_\lambda = \sum_{\lambda\in F} \phi'(x_\lambda) = \phi'(x)$$
so $\phi=\phi'$.